# How to watch the Windows registry for changes with Python

Tags: python, winapi, registry, pywin32

I want to watch a certain registry key for changes and do some automatic stuff as soon it changes with Python, e.g. a program changes registry keys during start up and I want to force the keys to the old values right after.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code-it-for-me request, not a programming problem.

Comment: I wanted to answer my own question according to [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Therefore I did not include my own research in the questions and just specified what my original questions was.

Should I include more research in the the original question in such cases or do you think the whole questions is too easily solved for Stack Overflow or otherwise off topic?

Comment: +1 Thank you for this addition to Stack Overflow. I don't use Windows much, but this looks useful. I'm pleased Python can do this task so parsimoniously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example code will force the calculator to start with the date time template regardless of the last used template. It uses [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) which provide a really quick way to access most of Windows internals and automate COM aware applications:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s', filename='watchRegistry.log')
log = logging.getLogger()

hiveToWatch = win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
keyToWatch = r'Software\Microsoft\Calc'

values = {(hiveToWatch, keyToWatch, 'DateTime'): (win32con.REG_DWORD, 1),
          (hiveToWatch, keyToWatch, 'Templates'): (win32con.REG_DWORD, 0),
          (hiveToWatch, keyToWatch, 'UnitConv'): (win32con.REG_DWORD, 0)}

while True:

    for (hive, key, valueName), (valueType, value) in values.items():
        handleWithSetRights = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(hive, key, 0, win32con.KEY_SET_VALUE)
        log.info(r'Setting %s\%s\%s = %s' % (hive, key, valueName, value))
        win32api.RegSetValueEx(handleWithSetRights, valueName, 0, valueType, value)
        win32api.RegCloseKey(handleWithSetRights)

    # Open and close the handle here as otherwise the set operation above will trigger a further round
    handleToBeWatched = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(hiveToWatch, keyToWatch, 0, win32con.KEY_NOTIFY)
    win32api.RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(handleToBeWatched, False, win32api.REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, None, False)
    win32api.RegCloseKey(handleToBeWatched)
```

Comment: Is it possible to list all windows registry keys using the Python Windows extensions  ?

Comment: You can see all functions available in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx). The functions to look at are RegEnumKey(Ex).

However, keep in mind that there are very many registry keys in case you want to enumerate all recursively.

Comment: For compatibility from Python 2.7 through 3.6 use `values.items()` instead of `values.iteritems()` (the latter is deprecated in 3.x and the performance of `items()` with older Python versions is negligible in this case).

Also, the backslashes in the `keyToWatch` initialization will be problematic for some keys - always specify raw when using backslashes that ought never be interpreted as escape sequences (`keyToWatch = r'Software\Microsoft\Calc'`).